# JSDoc for custom jQuery plugins with VS 2017 Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2017, jsdoc, javascript-intellisense

I'm adding a custom jQuery plugin to my code with the standard syntax (below). [Visual Studio 2017 supports JSDoc for Intellisense](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JavaScript-Language-Service-in-Visual-Studio), and I'm able to get it to work with normal functions, but I can't get it working with the jQuery plugin. What's the correct way to format the JSDoc for VS 2017 Intellisense?

Standard jQuery plugin format ([source](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)):

```js
$.fn.boxLoad = function (action) {
  // do stuff
};
```

Comment: 5 years later and still no joy :( can't believe this isn't implemented yet.